# Display authenticated user - Cordova Azure AD

Tags: cordova, authentication, azure-active-directory, display

I am able to authenticate using Azure AD but I would like to display the user name after login.

Edit: I am using **cordova-plugin-ms-azure-mobile-apps** plugin.

Here is the index.html code :

```
<button onclick="user" type='button' id='usr'>Get User</button>
```

And here is my index.js :

```
 //I am authenticating here
 client.login('aad').done(function (results) {
    alert("You are now signed in as: " + results.userId);

}, function (err) {
    alert("Error: " + err);

}, handleError);
    if (useOfflineSync) {
        initializeStore().then(setup);
    } else {
        setup();
    }
}

//here I am getting token 
var url = client.applicationUrl + '/.auth/me';
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('X-ZUMO-AUTH', 
client.currentUser.mobileServiceAuthenticationToken);
    fetch(url, { headers: headers })
        .then(function (data) {
            return data.json()
        }).then(function (user) {
            alert("Auth:" + user.usr);
            // The user object contains the claims for the authenticated user
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the username from the ID token that you can get back in the response or requested separately from AAD using an authorization code or via the implicit grant.

The password you cannot get.

Comment: @junnas thank you for your response. I am very new to Cordova, can you please explain it in more details?

Comment: I've never used cordova :/

Comment: @junnas I am using this line of code to authenticate and display user: client.login("aad").done(function (results) {
        alert("You are now signed in as: " + results.userId);
   }, function (err) {
        alert("Error: " + err);   However it doesnt display user.